# Stuck in Fastboot mode with "No valid slot to boot" after Magisk rooting attempt

Tags: rooting, magisk, google-pixel-3a-xl

For a Pixel 3a XL with an unlocked bootloader, I tried to flash a `boot.img` file patched by Magisk following [this guide](https://wccftech.com/how-to/root-google-pixel-3a-xl-using-magisk-tutorial/), using [`bonito-sp1a.210812.015`](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/bonito-sp1a.210812.015-factory-872afcc7.zip) from [Google Factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/images).

After I successfully completed the whole process from "Step 2: Rooting Google Pixel 3a XL" section and rebooted, my Pixel became stuck booting with a "G" logo (and progress bar animating).

I tried to fix it with these commands, which resulted in always booting in `Fastboot Mode`, error message `"No valid slot to boot"`.

```
./fastboot flash boot_a "boot.img"
./fastboot flash boot_b "boot.img"
```

---

**How can I make my Pixel boot normally again *without loosing any of my user data* living on it?**

**Alternatively, is there a way to back up all my user files from Pixel with eg. `adb`, given the broken booting?**

---

I'm able to boot in recovery mode if it can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sideloading in recovery mode with [full OTA](https://developers.google.com/android/ota#instructions) following the [official instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/ota#instructions) solved my problem: Pixel now boots properly; all my data is intact.